# Which small, light aircraft are suitable for operating at very high elevations?

Tags: aircraft-performance, general-aviation, cost, high-altitude

I live in [Jammu and Kashmir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jammu_and_Kashmir), in [an area](https://www.google.co.in/maps/@32.2291079,78.070289,14z) with an average elevation of 4,500m / 14,700ft MSL . I would like to know what would be a good and cheap light aircraft to carry 3-4 people for a 3-4 hour flight in that location for heights upto 23000ft as mountains are at least this high?
Runway length is 3700ft and asphalt. 
Budget is aroung $1 million to 1.5 preowned

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Can you tell us where you are? 4500m is over 14,000ft, which is [very high indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest_commercial_airports). We usually [don't answer 'shopping' questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site because they're very subjective and a lot depends on your personal situation. But if you focus on performance and other objective measures you might get a useful answer.

Comment: @Pondlife edited questions with details

Comment: I reworded your question a little, I hope I identified your location correctly but if not you can simply edit again

Comment: First of all, from many if not most people's standpoint, there is no such aircraft that qualifies as "cheap" (though I'm guessing in my American English you perhaps meant "inexpensive" because "good" and "cheap" don't really go to together), but that's a relative judgment; you may be wealthy. Next, to provide an intelligent opinion, one would need to know the runway lengths and surfaces you want to operate out of. Also, I'm guessing that avgas in your area might not be readily available. If so, you might want to limit your consideration to aircraft that can use Jet-A.

Comment: @Terry lenght = 1,125 meter surface Asphalt

Comment: What is your purchade budget?  What is your annual operating budget?  Is 100LL fuel readily available?

Comment: @murmansk Consider posting another question something like: "Is there a single-engine aircraft that can operate out of a 3,700 foot long runway at an elevation of xxxxx feet and climb to yyyyy feet with 4 adults aboard?" Replace xxxxx and yyyyy with appropriate values. I suggest using feet rather than meters because there are many here that might have good offhand info (i.e. the U.S. pilot population), but are not used to operating in meters and might not be inclined to take the time to convert.

Comment: You might want to check Indian regulations, too. In the US at 14,700 MSL you would be required to be pressurized or on supplemental oxygen. At 15,000 your passengers would need oxygen too if not pressurized.

Comment: None of this will be cheap.

Comment: Your Google Maps link doesn't point to any part of Jammu and Kashmir; it points to northern Himachal Pradesh.

Comment: @Sean someone edited it not me

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that location is going to present you with a lot of problems, most notably with density altitude and mountain flying.  This is also going to depend on the airports and runway lengths available as well as obstacle clearance altitudes for the area in question.  Most likely it's going to be a turbine powered aircraft which is pressurized for comfort and features good Short Takeoff and Landing (STOL) characteristics and soft field operations.

This question will probably be put on hold shortly, primarily because it is opinion based, but I would recommend a [Quest Kodiak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quest_Kodiak) or a [Pilatus PC-6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilatus_PC-6_Porter) for the role due to meeting most of that criteria minus being non-pressurized.  You would just need to provide supplemental oxygen for the crew and passengers during the flight.  Another aircraft which would be recommended is a [Pilatus PC-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilatus_PC-12) or the soon to be released [Cessna Denali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_Denali) as they meet all of these needs albeit is a bit larger and less capable as a STOL aircraft.

Comment: The Maule might also work. http://www.mauleflight.com/faq/M7-260C.html

Comment: You would have to, at the least, have a turbocharged engine for operations at those altitudes.

Comment: I was going to suggest a PC-12 as well but that's on the high end of your budget at best.